# ST_Intersection not works as expected with postgis

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, geos

I'm using `ST_Intersection` function in **Postgis** with a **Multipoint** and **Polygon** geometries and I can't figure out the result of it.

Here an example of my SQL request using ST_Intersection :

```sql
    SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_Intersection(
            ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(1 1, 1 1)'),
            ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))')
        )
    );
```

**Output :**

```sql
    'POINT(1 1)' /* I expected MULTIPOINT(1 1, 1 1) as result */
```

As we can see `ST_Intersection` has removed the duplicates and that's not what I expected
*The result is the same for all lib using GEOSlib*

In a mathematical approach, let's consider 2 sets of number :
*Logically, the intersection of these two sets must return all the numbers included in both even if they are duplicates like this:*

**S1 = {1, 2, 3, 4} 

S2 = {1, 1} 

S1 *intersection* S2 = {1, 1}**

So, am I missing something ?

Comment: If you want to take a "mathematical" approach why are you treating sets as something *that can contain duplicate values*? That would be a [bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), not a set.

Comment: Oh! my bad, so I just did some search about intersection of bags and I found my answer here 
https://cs.appstate.edu/~dap/classes/1100/sect2_2.html
So intersection of two bags removes duplicate
Thank you for your comment !

Comment: You could write an answer for your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike a [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)), a [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) can contain duplicates elements but the result of an [intersection of two multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Basic_properties_and_operations) is a multiset that contains the minimum multiplicity of an element of both multisets.

For example : `{1,1,2,3} intersection {1,2,2,4} = {1,2}`

So `ST_intersection(Geometry A, Geometry B)` will remove duplicates included in both geometries